# Как сделать пропадающую приклеенную шапку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Проблема такова: есть шапка на сайте, приклеенная к верху экрана (position : fixed), и при помощи jQuery отслеживается положение страницы и при скролле вниз больше 300 px выполняется .SlideUp()  на весь header. Но если обновить страницу по середине экрана, шапка появляется. Что делать?

Comment: отслеживать положение страницы более тщательно

Comment: А можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 2):

Отслеживайте положение страницы не только при скроллинге, а так же при отрытии документа. Например:

```js
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", checkScroll );
function checkScroll () {
   if (document.body.scrollTop>300) header.SlideUp();
};
```